# changing just the height of the UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

how can i set the height of `UIImageView` and leaving other attributes as it is from the .xib? i have `UIImageView` in .xib file but i only want to set height of it programmatically. can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It can be done. For eg: If you have `UIImageView` as imageView then do the below to change the specific frame value.

**Way - 1**

```
CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
rect.size.height = /* YOUR_HEIGHT */;
imageView.frame = rect;
```

**Way - 2**

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x, imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, /* YOUR_HEIGHT */);
```

Comment: code is working, but there seems to be some other issue, the imageView has constraint of height 1 in the .xib and i want the height of 0.5, but its not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to add https://github.com/AlexDenisov/FrameAccessor to your project. It allows to work with frame directly, for example:

```
view.x = 15.;
view.width = 167.;
```